# uigesturerecognizer in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

Hello I want to emulate a long a press button? how can I do this? I think a timer is needed. Can you help me? I see `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` but how can I utilize this type?

here is the code , it isn't recognize long press

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
[self.button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
[longPress release];

- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {
         NSLog(@"Long Press");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use `- (IBAction)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture `

Comment: Check `minimumPressDuration` property. _The time interval is in seconds. The default duration is is 0.5 seconds._

Answer (score 2):

In order to utilize `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` you must set the `minimumPressDuration` property. This specifies how long to wait until your gesture recognizer is fired. For example

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)] autorelease];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 2.0f;
[self.button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {
         NSLog(@"Long Press");
    }
}
```